# Message queue over high latency WAN?

Tags: message-queue, wan

Is there a message queue system optimized for a WAN with >200ms RTT? E.g., sending messages from US to Asia.

I'm looking for a MQ that can batch messages together, pipeline lots of messages across multiple TCP connections, and/or use UDP to blast messages (like UDT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions which I can think of which fit the problem statement you have described, if you are using Kafka for message queueing within a single geographical location. Reliability of message delivery and latency optimizations would be 2 key goals for your project.

Kafka community has a MirrorMaker tool (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330), which has been extended by Uber, in form of ureplicator
(https://eng.uber.com/ureplicator/).

Comment: That's looks promising, but I can't tell if they optimize for transmission over a high latency link. If it's just 1 connection, it's going to be slow.

Comment: So, Kafka has the notion of partitions, and thats what makes it a high throughput queueing system. Multiple producers/consumers can write/read to/from different partitions simultaneously. So, if wan throughput is your concern, you could sufficiently partition your topic on both sides of the wan, so that your kafkamirror/ureplicator spawn one tcp connection per destination partition, thereby achieving higher throughput. Note that to get ordering guarantees within a partition, kafka allows only one consumer (each consumer group) for a single partition.